# Visual Studio 2022 generates invalid syntax from typelib

Tags: visual-studio, typelib

I used the *Project > Add New Item* tool in Visual Studio 2022 and selected *MFC Class From TypeLib*. In the dialog which appeared, I selected "File" from the *Implement interface from* dropdown list and in the *Location* field I entered the path to the `.tlb` file from a third-party package. I selected a handful of interfaces to be used and clicked the **OK** button to confirm the request. Most of the code generated was as it should be, but in a few places the definitions contained invalid syntax caused by a missing argument specifier. For example:

```cpp
    LPUNKNOWN get_FX()
    {
        LPUNKNOWN result;
        InvokeHelper(0xa, DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, , (void*)&result, nullptr);
        return result;
    }
```

Note the single space character between the two otherwise adjacent commas.

Visual Studio itself recognizes there's a problem with what it has generated when it tries to compile the resulting code.

> C2059 syntax error: ','

I have confirmed this behavior with earlier versions of the IDE. Is this a known bug in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for not closing the loop sooner. I filed a [bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-2022-generates-invalid-syn/10206982) with Microsoft, and they fixed the bug last month in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.6.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to rename some things. This is what you have to do if you #import office type library

#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE16\mso.dll" rename("RGB", "MSRGB") rename("DocumentProperties", "WordDocumentProperties")
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA6\VBE6EXT.OLB" raw_interfaces_only, rename("Reference", "ignorethis"), rename("VBE", "testVBE")
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Excel.exe" exclude("IFont", "IPicture") rename("RGB", "ignorethis"), rename("DialogBox", "ignorethis"), rename("VBE", "testVBE"), rename("ReplaceText", "EReplaceText"), rename("CopyFile","ECopyFile"), rename("FindText", "EFindText"), rename("NoPrompt", "ENoPrompt")